# how to refine the regex for conditions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I use the following code to get data,as the data in text has two different structure, I need to make some judgment. the following codes can works, but I think it's really not a good one.

I'm a beginner in RE, I searched some articles, but I haven't found a way to refine it.

how to refine the following code?

```
import re
import html
import json

filepath="D:/Response.txt"
data=open(filepath,'r', encoding='utf-16').read()

rex1 = "msgList = '({.*?})'"
rex2='"general_msg_list":"({.*?})"'

def get_art(data,rex):
    pattern = re.compile(pattern=rex, flags=re.S)
    match = pattern.search(data)
    if match:
        data = match.group(1).replace('\\','')
        # there is some difference for data.
        if rex=="msgList = '({.*?})'":
            data = html.unescape(data)
        data = json.loads(data)
        articles = data.get("list")
        for item in articles:
            print('\nthe result is:\n',item)

with open(filepath,'r', encoding='utf-16') as fp:  
   line = fp.readline()
   while line:
       try:
           get_art(line.strip(),rex1)
       except:
           pass
       try:
           get_art(line.strip(),rex2)
       except:
           pass
       line = fp.readline()
```

I need to catch the data in (msgList =....) or (general_msg_list":"...). and convert the string to json. for the data in (msgList =....), I found I need to use "data = html.unescape(data)", while if I use "data = html.unescape(data)" in (general_msg_list":"...), there would be error.

currently, I use

```
try:
    get_art(line.strip(),rex1)
except:
    pass
try:
    get_art(line.strip(),rex2)
except:
    pass
```

I think there should be a better way to replace it.

maybe a better way is I read the whole file, not line by line. the problem for me is I have difficulty to deal with the while file data, that's why I read it line by line.

Comment: What do you want to catch?

Comment: I need to catch the data in (msgList =....) or  (general_msg_list":"...). and convert the string to json. for the data in  (msgList =....), I found I need to use "data = html.unescape(data)", while if I use "data = html.unescape(data)" in (general_msg_list":"...), there would be error.

Comment: currently, I use  `try:
           get_art(line.strip(),rex1)
       except:
           pass
       try:
           get_art(line.strip(),rex2)
       except:
           pass`  , I think there should be a better way to replace it.

Comment: Edit it in the main text.